# How to combine 2 SQLs into single SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Table C(id, type) has list of all unique clients ids,  with and without transactions. Every id is unique and has a single type.

Table T(date, id, type, money) is  the transaction table, the id is not unique here.

Table C has more unique ids than in T, because not all clients are doing transactions.
The unique ids in the T table are subset of id's in the C table.

### SQL for  AVG(money) and STD(money) per  type  for   T table:

```
SELECT
type,
AVG(money) AS avg_for_active_clients,
STDEV(money) AS stdev_for_active_clients,
COUNT(DISTINCT id) as cnt_active_clients
FROM (
  SELECT id , type, sum(money) as money 
  FROM T
  GROUP BY id, type
) A
GROUP BY type
```

### SQL for  AVG(money) and STD(money) per  type  for C table:

```
SELECT  
type,
AVG(money) AS avg_for_all_clients,
STDEV(money) stdev_for_all_clients,
COUNT(DISTINCT id) as cnt_all_clients
FROM (
  SELECT C.id, C.type , COALESCE(A.money, 0) as money FROM C 
  LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT id ,   sum(money) as money 
      FROM T
      GROUP BY  id 
  ) A
  ON C.id = A.id
) B
GROUP BY type
```

Is it possible to combine 2 SQLs above into single SQL ?
My database is Redshift.

Comment: Combine how? Please show us sample data, current results of both queries, and the result you would like to get.

Comment: Is your "type" field in the Table T has full functional dependency on "id"? In other words, is the relation between the fields "type" and "id" in Table T always one-to-one? If yes, then your 2nd query is superset of your 1st query.

Comment: id <-> type is 1:1  
STDEV and AVG in 2nd query is different from STDEV and AVG in 1st,  ( there is LEFT join and coalesce in 2nd SQL) hence the 2nd query is NOT a superset of 1st.
Table T is huge, I would like to scan it once only.

Comment: I would like combine horizontally, without UNION ALL

Answer (score 0):

You can combine your `select #1` with your `select #2` vertically or horizontally.

To combine them vertically you can use `UNION ALL`. For example:

```
select #1
union all
select #2
```

To combine them horizontally you can use `FULL JOIN`. For example:

```
select *
from (
  select #1
) x
full join (
  select #2
) y on y.type = x.type
```

Comment: I would like to combine horizontally; the table T is huge, I would like to query it only once